# How to filx "'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed" with Pandas and NumPy

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following code, where I read with Pandas a CSV file to create one 'Dataframe' (the attributeValues) and a 'Series' (the attributeClassValues).

```
dataSegmentToProcess = pd.read_csv('myCSV', nrows=2000, header=None)

attributeValues = dataSegmentToProcess[dataSegmentToProcess.columns[:-1]]
attributeClassValues = dataSegmentToProcess[dataSegmentToProcess.columns[-1]]
```

Then, in the for loop, below I got the error "***`Series` objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed***" in the last line of my code:

```
   means = np.zeros([numberOfUniqueClasses, dimension])
   for i in range(numberOfUniqueClasses):
     idx = (attributeClassValues == uniqueClasses[i])
     means[i, :] = np.mean(attributeValues[idx, :], axis=0)
```

'numberOfUniqueClasses' and 'dimension' are integers.

The `attributeValues` is a dataframe, not a series object, so how come I get this error?

Any idea will be welcomed!

PS: I can do my job with the 'read_csv` (without Pandas), but for obvious reasons, I prefer using Pandas.

Comment: What type of object is means?

Comment: Edited above, sorry.